# How to unhide element

Tags: jquery

I worked on an dropdown list that when a dropdown list item is clicked some radio buttons are displayed below. The question is how can I unhide the radiobuttons? I already know that I'm very far with my code, only the last step is still missing. The thing I want is to say, everytime the selectString is **Selecteer een verstiging** dont show .locationRB class. But I dont know how to do it.
this is what I have already:

```
//Unhided radiobuttons
  jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ) .hide(); //

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging').change(function() {

    var selectedString = $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging option:selected').text()

    console.log( selectedString )

    if( selectedString !== "(Selecteer een vestiging)" ){
      console.log( 'show' );
    }else{
      console.log( 'hide' );
    }


});
```

Answer (score 2):

To show:

```
$( 'div.locationRB' ).show();
```

To hide:

```
$( 'div.locationRB' ).hide();
```

I see you have a boolean condition, so you can use toggle:

```
var willshow = selectedString !== "(Selecteer een vestiging)";
$( 'div.locationRB' ).toggle(willshow);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.show()`  to show 
and `.hide()` to hide the content

Use

```
jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ).show();  // Show the particular div

jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ).hide();  // hide the particular div
```

Also there is a **missing closing braces** for the change event .. Fix that and it should be fine

**FULL CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.locationRB').hide();

    $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging').change(function() {
        var selectedString = $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging option:selected').text()

        console.log(selectedString)

        if (selectedString !== "(Selecteer een vestiging)") {
            jQuery('div.locationRB').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('div.locationRB').hide();
        }
    }).change();
});​
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CdN63/)**

Comment: You *can* actually have spaces where he has them.  It's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with required changes...

```
//Unhided radiobuttons
jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ).hide(); //

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging').change(function() {

        var selectedString = $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging option:selected').text()

        console.log( selectedString )

        if( selectedString !== "(Selecteer een vestiging)" ){
            jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ).show();
        }else{
            jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Archer, your script will failed since it is missing closing bracket "});" for the $.change() function.

Comment: @nolabel - thanks for spotting that.  It was copied and pasted from the question and I missed that he'd missed it :)

Answer (score 0):

AmirsBay, add "});" to close your $.change() function. Your script should show in your console log. That is what you are missing. You are well on the right track.

```
//Unhided radiobuttons
  jQuery( 'div.locationRB' ) .hide(); //

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging').change(function() {

    var selectedString = $('.wijzigingOpvangVestiging option:selected').text()

    console.log( selectedString )

    if( selectedString !== "(Selecteer een vestiging)" ){
      console.log( 'show' );
    }else{
      console.log( 'hide' );
    }

  }); //<--- you are missing this
});
```